# How to print user's message in telegram bot?

Tags: python, py-telegram-bot-api

I'm making a telegram bot that supposed to ask users for ID and print it out in terminal

```py
import telebot
from time import sleep

bot = telebot.TeleBot('BOT TOKEN')

from telebot import types

user_message = ''


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):

    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Send ID")
    markup.add(btn1)
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Ok, let's start!", reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):

    if message.text == 'Send ID':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Ok, send it please!')
        global user_message
        user_message = message.text


print(user_message)
bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

I tried waiting for five seconds after user presses 'Send ID' button and print the message. But it prints 'Send ID'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this function `message` is something fixed throughout the function execution, message does not change within. And the function is doing something only when `message.text == 'Send ID'`, so there's no reason for anything else to be printed.

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):

    if message.text == 'Send ID':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Ok, send it please!')
        global user_message
        user_message = message.text
print(user_message)
bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

One way to deal with it - to add another `if`, which will process all other texts:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):

    if message.text == 'Send ID':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Ok, send it please!')
        global user_message
        user_message = message.text
    else:
        user_message = message.text
```

That way the dialog will look like this:

```
- Bot: "Ok, let's start!"
- You: "Send ID"
- Bot: "Ok, send it please!"
- You: "1234"
```

And `user_message` is going to become "1234" in the end.

---

Downside of this approach is that if you have more complicated logic with more different responses expected from the user, this if/elif/else method won't be able to differentiate them.

You can look into `telebot` [states](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/custom_states.py) in their official repo which help the bot understand what scenario the user is currently in.

I also have a [github repository](https://github.com/mskozlova/ydb_serverless_telegram_bot/blob/main/README.md) with a template for dialog bot where telebot states are used, which may be of help.